# how to append a list of of lists with different lengths

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to use a list of lists to add rows to a dataframe.

The error is as follows:
IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.

The code is below:

```
Total_List = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12],[13,14,15]]

Some_List = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4']

first_row = {'A': [0], 'B': [0], 'C': [0]}
All_Rows = pd.DataFrame(first_row)

#Optimized_Trades

for i in range(len(Some_List)):
    for j in range(len(Some_List[i])):
        df_temp = { 'A': Total_List[i][j], 'B': Total_List[i][j], 'C': Total_List[i][j]}
        All_Rows = All_Rows.append(df_temp, ignore_index = True)

All_Trades = All_Trades[1:]
        
display(All_Trades)
```

Ideally, the final output would be:

```
1,4,7,10,13
2,5,8,11,14
3,6,9,12,15
```

Comment: What are `list_a`, `list_b`, and `list_c`? Can you post the full traceback of the error?

Comment: Thank you for pointing out this error. I have since corrected it. Please let me know if there is anything else I can clarify, I know things are everywhere.

Comment: Try `pd.DataFrame(Total_List).T` or `pd.DataFrame(zip(* Total_List)))`.. more details in my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you want to add each of the `first, second ... nth` elements of each sublist as rows of the data frame, which is equivalent to the dataframe of the `transpose of the list of lists`.

You don't need a for loop to do this in python.

#### Using zip with unpacking operator

You can do it in a few ways but the one way would be [zip](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/zip) with [unpacking operator](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/) `*` using `list(zip(*l))`

```
l = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12],[13,14,15]]

lt = pd.DataFrame(zip(*l)) #<---
print(lt)
```

```
   0  1  2   3   4
0  1  4  7  10  13
1  2  5  8  11  14
2  3  6  9  12  15
```

#### Using pandas transpose

A simpler way would be to use pandas to do this where you can simply use [transpose](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html) -

```
l = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12],[13,14,15]]

lt = pd.DataFrame(l).T  #<---
print(lt)
```

```
   0  1  2   3   4
0  1  4  7  10  13
1  2  5  8  11  14
2  3  6  9  12  15
```